# Determine xml structure from c# code

Tags: c#, xml

Is it possible to accurately determine the structure of XML file by reading C# code.

Code:

```
XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
            xDoc.Load(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "\\Contacts.xml");

            XmlNodeList nodeList = xDoc.SelectNodes("/ContactsList/Group[@Name='" + group_name + "']");

            if (nodeList[0].ChildNodes[2].InnerText != "NA")
            {
                if ((now < start) || (now > end))
                {
                    primary_number = nodeList[0].ChildNodes[2].InnerText;
                }
                else
                    primary_number = nodeList[0].ChildNodes[0].InnerText;

            }
            else
                primary_number = nodeList[0].ChildNodes[0].InnerText;


            if (nodeList[0].ChildNodes[3].InnerText != "NA")
            {
                if ((now < start) || (now > end))
                {
                    secondary_number = nodeList[0].ChildNodes[3].InnerText;
                }
                else
                    secondary_number = nodeList[0].ChildNodes[1].InnerText;
            }
            else
                secondary_number = nodeList[0].ChildNodes[1].InnerText;

        }
```

I can't find the  xml file and i am trying to reproduce the structure of the Contacts.xml file.

Comment: You can't get the tag names from the code above.  Only the index number so you never can duplicate the actual xml file.

Comment: @jdweng But can we get a XML skeleton by getting some clues from `SelectNodes`?